Issue with concept to check that elements of parameter pack are either float or double
I've written the following C++23 code and encountered an issue.  In my code, I defined a concept to check if a sequence consists of float and double types.  Using this concept, I defined the ChTest() function. However, the compiler behaves differently when using the requires clause versus not using it.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept IsFloat = std::is_same_v<T, float>;

template <typename T>
concept IsDouble = std::is_same_v<T, double>;

constexpr bool isValidSequence()
{
    return true;
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
constexpr bool isValidSequence(First, Rest... rest)
{
    if constexpr (IsFloat<First>)
        return (IsFloat<Rest> && ...) || isValidSequence(rest...);
    else if constexpr (IsDouble<First>)
        return (IsDouble<Rest> && ...);

    return false;
}

template <typename... Args>
concept FloatDoubleSequence = isValidSequence(Args{}...);

#if 0 // with requires
template <typename... Args>
requires FloatDoubleSequence<Args...>
#else // without requires
template <FloatDoubleSequence... Args>
#endif
void ChTest(Args... args)
{
}

int main()
{
    ChTest(1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6);  // Valid
    ChTest(1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f);                 // Valid
    ChTest(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);                    // Valid
    ChTest(1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4, 5.5);       // Valid
    ChTest(3.3f, 4.4, 5.5f);                  // With requires, the compiler correctly gives an error, but without requires, it does not. It should give an error in both cases.

    return 0;
}

Issue
In the code above, I defined the ChTest() function with and without requires. The second call, e.i. ChTest(3.3f, 4.4, 5.5f), correctly gives an error when compiled with requires, but does not give an error without requires. It should give an error in both cases.
Expected Behavior
The compiler should give an error for the invalid sequence in both cases (with or without requires).
What is the reason for this behavior? How can I get the same error without using requires?

template <FloatDoubleSequence... Args> means that all Args must satisfy FloatDoubleSequence, that is, (FloatDoubleSequence<Args> && ...) which is not FloatDoubleSequence<Args...>.

There is already a good answer. I just try to put the same in simpler terms.
This
template <SomeConcept... Args>           // I

Places a constraint on each element of the parameter pack. Every single type must fullfill SomeConcept.
On the other hand this:
template <typename... Args>
requires SomeConcept<Args...>           // II

Applies the concepts to the parameter pack as a whole.
The difference you see for the following call is just that difference.
ChTest(3.3f, 4.4, 5.5f);

I- requires each deduced types meets the concept. A single float or a single double is a a FloatDoubleSequence.
II- requires that the whole parameter pack meets the concept. The first and last parameters are float the middle one is double, hence Args... is no FloatDoubleSequence.

Summary: Your false premise is that the two variants are effectively the same. They are not. One constraints each type of the pack, the other constraints the whole pack, and that's the difference you see.

template <typename... Args> requires FloatDoubleSequence<Args...> checks the whole sequence matches your requirement. template <FloatDoubleSequence... Args> checks that each of Args matches FloatDoubleSequence individually.
Your failing case is a float following a double, which won't be caught by testing each parameter on its own.
The equivalent requires to your second case is
template <typename... Args> requires (FloatDoubleSequence<Args> && ...). There isn't an constrained template parameter equivalent to your desired behaviour.

I think I'm stuck somewhere small and failing. Do you have a suggestion?

@VeNToR why doesn't requires FloatDoubleSequence<Args...> work for you? There's no X such that you can write template<X... Args> and meet your requirements, template parameter constraints just don't work that way

with requires, it works... so it means that I have to use requires right ?
